# How to count how many times each individual word appears in text file

Tags: javascript

I have a challenge where I need to find how many times each **individual** word appears in this textfile. You can ignore punctuation and capitalisation.

My aim to achieve this is:

- To find a way to read a file and save it to a variable <--- done
- To remove some of the unnecessary white space (not the space in between words)
- Find a way to write some regex which would ignore words that are punctuated and capitalised
- Store the new refactored story in a new variable
- Somehow call (split)   and store the words in an ordered array

That is how far I have got in my head so far. I obviously am not at the point where I can write code to group the words by their length.

However, I found this code which I believe will help me but I can't make sense of it and I think it is what I am looking for. Could someone walk me through it?

This is an example of what I am looking to work from: http://textuploader.com/dq68g

```
CountUniqueWords.prototype.countWords = function(line) {
  var self = this;
  var uniqueWords = self._uniqueWords || {};
  var words = line.match(/(?!\d)(\w+\b)/g, '');
  var word;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; words ? i < words.length : 0; i++) {
    word = words[i].toLowerCase();

    uniqueWords[word] = uniqueWords[word] ?
      uniqueWords[word] += 1 : 1;
  }

  return uniqueWords;
};
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
fileContent
    // lowercase
    .toLowerCase()
    // remove non-words
    .replace(/\W/g, " ")
    // split by space, tab and newline
    .split(/\s+/)
    // remove empty entries
    .filter(v => !!v)
    // count all terms
    .reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {});
```

```js
var content = `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a sentence that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice, testing typewriters and computer keyboards, displaying examples of fonts, and other applications involving text where the use of all letters in the alphabet is desired. Owing to its brevity and coherence, it has become widely known.`;

console.log(get_terms(content));

function get_terms(corpus){
    return corpus
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/\W/g, " ")
        .split(/\s+/)
        .filter(v => !!v)
        .reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {});
}
```

Unfortunately, ES does not support any ordered dictionary. You might have to implement your own data structure for that purpose.

Comment: The following assumptions can be made:

It Ignores punctuation and capitalisation?

Comment: @dogcourage Punctuations are ignored (`.replace(/\W/g, " ")`), and uppercase letters are turned into lowercase (`.toLowerCase()`).

Comment: Great! Thank you.